# Foreman conditional running processes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, foreman

I have a foreman app with a Procfile like this

```
web: bundle exec rails s
custom_process: bundle exec rake custom:process
faking_custom_process: bundle exec rake custom:faking_process
```

And I want to run `custom_process` or `faking custom_process` depends on my needs:

```
foreman start # run web & custom_process
FAKING_PROCESS # run web & faking_custom_process
```

Yes, I know about ability of running like that `foreman start -c faking_custom_process=0`, but this is more difficult than I expect, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no option in foreman to just skip a process. I think you'd need to extend your start invocation to do something different too if you want to run the other processes. Otherwise you're just telling it to run zero copies of `faking_custom_process` and nothing else:

```
foreman start -m web=1,custom_process=1,faking_custom_process=0
```

or for the faking version:

```
foreman start -m web=1,custom_process=0,faking_custom_process=1
```

You could of course script that so you've got two scripts running those different versions.

---

An alternative would be to switch faking on or off using a variable in the environment (I'm not convinced it's any easier but it's an alternative):

```
web: bundle exec rails d
custom_process: PROCESS=$FAKING"process" && bundle exec rake custom:$PROCESS
```

A normal `foreman start` will just run `bundle exec rake custom:process`.

For the faking equivalent you can do:

```
export FAKING="faking_"
```

which will mean that from then on `foreman start` it will call `bundle exec rake custom:faking_process` instead.

You can return to the normal process by clearing the `FAKING` variable with:

```
export FAKING=
```

You could of course encapsulate that into a shell script too.

Comment: Thanks for help, but this seems little strange for me, because of there is no way to solve this issue beautiful

Comment: There is this (closed) issue on the gem : https://github.com/ddollar/foreman/issues/466 . The work around suggests using `all=1` so your call would be `foreman start -c all=1,faking_custom_process=0`.

Comment: Oh, ok!

I think I can close the issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use .profile to store default options for `foreman start`:

```
concurrency: web=1,custom_process=1,faking_custom_process=0
```

or using shortcut:

```
concurrency: all=1,faking_custom_process=0
```

And then you override this default option to switch to fake process:

```
foreman start -c all=1,custom_process=0
```

See: http://ddollar.github.io/foreman/#DEFAULT-OPTIONS